# How to add extra image field in Manage Products Form?

Tags: custom-options, products-management

[image]How to add extra upload files field in Magento admin manage products section?

Answer (score 0):

Create a media image type attribute and set that in the product attribute sets

Go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Add New`

In the drop down for `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` choose `Media Image`

Once created go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets`and click on the attribute set you want to add it to. Drag the newly created attribute to that tab.

Here are some links that I found:

- http://www.kalenyuk.com.ua/add-new-image-for-product-in-magento-81.html
- http://sarathlal.com/create-and-use-custom-image-attribute-in-magento/